# Data collection frameworks like ODK

Tags: android, mobile, frameworks, data-collection, odk

I am working on one of my assignments which has a requirement for  data collection, reporting and aggregation. I have already explored ODK (collect and aggregate) which satisfies maximum requirement. Before finalizing ODK, I wanted to know whether there are any such similar solutions that I should refer, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting directly from the ODK FAQ page : https://opendatakit.org/help/faq

Of course! There are many other data collection systems that might work better for you. Some of them use ODK in some way (FormHub, EpiSurveyor, DoForms, Group Complete, KoBo Toolbox, Survey CTO, ViewWorld, PhiCollect) while others are ODK compatible (JavaRosa, OpenXData, RapidSMS).

There are also great systems that were designed more for SMS (FrontlineSMS, Ushahidi), systems that work on iOS (iFormBuilder), even systems that work on Palm Pilots and Windows Mobile (Pendragon Forms, CyberTracker) and Nokias (Nokia Data Gathering).

If you want to find out more, MobileActive is a great place to learn more about data collection. Mobile Data Collection Tools - Comparison Matrix and Mobile-Phone-Based Data Collection Systems Comparison Table, Mobile and Web Technologies for Social and Economic Development report, Comparing Mobile Solutions for GIS Data Collection and Display, and Nomad Mobile Collection Systems Decision Tool are also good resources.